# Suppose that an instruction encoding format has 4 bits for argument registers. How many registers is the architecture most likely to have?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Working through some material on CPU architecture and am unsure on the following question:

*Suppose that an instruction encoding format has 4 bits for argument registers. How many registers is the architecture most likely to have? Why?*

What is the general principle is here - how the size of argument registers corresponds to the total of registers

Comment: Size of *argument register encoding in instructions* vs. *number of architectural registers*.

Comment: Using $4$ bits, you can encode how many registers? These are the basics.

Comment: There is x86 64 bit with 3 bits and 16 registers. And about 180 or so rename registers to support out-of-order execution.